# why is my vfl not working?

Tags: swift, autolayout

I have the following code which I am trying to implement a dynamic image added to a vertical scroll view. I would like to have its constraints so the image sets itself inside the borders of the scrollView.

However the results are that the image seems to remain in its original size (which is bigger then the scrollview so the image gets cropped)

Here is the code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myScrollView: UIScrollView!
private let lettersModel:LettersModel = LettersModel();
private var imgs = [UIImageView]();

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myScrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor()

    for var index=0; index<1; index++
    {

        let myImage:UIImage = UIImage(named: lettersModel.getLetterAt(index))!
        let myImageView:UIImageView = UIImageView()
        myImageView.image = myImage
        myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit

        myScrollView.addSubview(myImageView)

        myImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

        myScrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[myImageView]-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views:["myImageView":myImageView] ))

        imgs.append(myImageView)

    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think you should be calling `view.addSubview(myScrollView)`, it should already be attached by SB.

Comment: You also need to set the contentSize of `myScrollView` so that it knows it has more things to display.

Comment: @sschala you are right I removed view.addSubview(myScrollView)  , but still images are not layed out well . myScrollView constraints are set from storyboard , adding the content size (just tried 300*1000) did not help. Thanks

Comment: Can you check that your scrollView width equal to the screen width?

Comment: view.frame.width = 1024 , scrollView.frame.width = 125 , scrollview.contenSize.width=0

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do in more details?

Comment: I would like to have a vertical scroller on the right side of the screen with images inside that are loaded dynamically and fit into the scroller width

Comment: And you don't want to use CollectionView? (But this should look like collectionView, right?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIView`'s inside a `UIScrollView` can't size to it's parent. You can create a UIView inside the UIScrollView and update the width in `layoutSubviews` and add all UIView inside that UIView. Here is how you can do that: (For this to work you need to set the height of the contentSize of the `UIScrollView` but you also have to set this in order to make it scroll.)

```
class MyScrollView : UIScrollView {

    let contentView = UIView()

    override init (frame : CGRect) {
        super.init(frame : frame)
        addSubview(contentView)
    }

    convenience init () {
        self.init(frame:CGRect.zero)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("This class does not support NSCoding")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        contentView.frame.size.width = frame.width
        contentView.frame.size.height = contentSize.height
        super.layoutSubviews()
    }
}

var myScrollView = MyScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 600))
var imgs = [UIImageView]();

let myImage = UIImage(named: "achtergrond")
let myImageView:UIImageView = UIImageView()
myImageView.image = myImage
myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit

myScrollView.contentSize.height = 1000 // <-- setting the contentSize
myScrollView.contentView.addSubview(myImageView) // <-- You add the UIImageView to the contentView

myImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
myScrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[myImageView]-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views:["myImageView":myImageView] ))

imgs.append(myImageView)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to activate them like below, just edit code for your implementation.

```
var allConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
var constraintName = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[myImageView]-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views:["myImageView":myImageView])
NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(allConstraints)
```